# Vagrant up script reports gulp command not found but ssh in and it runs no problem

Tags: gulp, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm setting up a vagrant box for my doc dept. and when I attempt to start `gulp --gulpfile /vagrant/gulpfile.js serve` it reports `gulp: command not found`. If I `vagrant ssh` and run the same command everything is okay. I have other boxes that start various tools in the script so I'm at a lost as to why this is failing.

Can anyone tell me why `gulp` is not found from the `vagrant up` script?

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "cabike/MeanXenial"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000
  config.vm.provision "deploy",
      run: "always",
      type: "shell",
      inline: <<-SHELL
        gulp --gulpfile /vagrant/gulpfile.js serve
      SHELL
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It might really be that gulp is installed for your `vagrant` user but you're running your script as `root` user

You can change this behaviour by using the [`privileged`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html) option

> `privileged` (boolean) - Specifies whether to execute the shell script
>   as a privileged user or not (`sudo`). By default this is "true".

The provisioning will become

```
  config.vm.provision "deploy",
      run: "always",
      privileged: false,
      type: "shell",
      inline: <<-SHELL
        gulp --gulpfile /vagrant/gulpfile.js serve
      SHELL
```